# Python-pypi registration error using cmd

Tags: python, pypi

I have just started to learn Python and created my first module. I wanted to upload to Pypi so I registered on the site manually and following it I tried to run at CMD. I run command as following:

[image: Registration command]

I have searched all over the internet but I'm not finding anything regarding this thing and as I'm just few days old in python really not getting much idea what to do,so help me!!

Comment: what command are you running? what error are you getting? pls update the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a **.pypirc** file in your Home directory in.

It should contain this

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
  pypi
  pypitest

[pypi]
repository=https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username=your_username
password=your_password

[pypitest]
repository=https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
username=your_username
password=your_password
```

This will correct the path to https as your error suggests

Comment: which home directory?